# Creating a new NodeId in OPC UA

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, milo

Dear stackoverflowers,

If I want to make a NodeId in the Identifiers.java file of Eclipse Milo with Ns=3 and S='Counters' what kind of init(**number**) should I have?

The return method for the value is:

```
 private static NodeId init(int value) {
         return new NodeId(Unsigned.ushort(0), Unsigned.uint(value));
     }
```

This is the best way I could explain it because I'm not sure myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is for the built-in NodeIds belonging to namespace 0. You shouldn't be defining nodes in there.

You're free to define your own NodeIds ahead of time but the only answer to which namespace index they belong to is "it depends". The index should correspond to the index in the NamespaceUri array of the URI belonging to the Namespace you add them to...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kevin and sorry for the confusion..

Now I created a new NodeId (one in the PLC):
http://imgur.com/VOBS09Z

In the client you could see how it is structured:
http://imgur.com/a/Ym4I5

This is giving me a null value back but I expected the sourceTimestamp and SourcePicoseconds how come..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not using the same NodeId as in that picture. The quote marks you're seeing in UaExpert are actually part of the NodeId.

Comment: It works. I can read out the value of the NodeId. Thanks Kevin. I really appreciate it.

Last question I assume the client is using binary encoding. Don't know sure how to see it except from the opc.tcp endpoint filter but what would you suggest me to do if I want to use XML encoding. 

This is a requirement for my assignment that's why. And OPC UA is unique because of this functionality so I would assume it isn't a weird requirement.

Comment: @LamarSt you'll need to find a server that supports HTTP/S transport and XML encoding. Most real world servers do not. Especially the servers embedded in PLCs.